# Is there a method for generating dynamic tests in Nightwatch.js similar to Mocha.js?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Mocha.JS has a method for generating dynamic calls based on parameters as seen here:
https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests

Is there a built in method for doing the same thing for Nightwatch.JS with URL's and input tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Night watch now includes a Mocha test runner.  Using the mocha test runner you can generate dynamic tests.